# How to create a transparent filter that don't process touch events

Tags: android, filter, transparent

I would like to apply a sort of semi-transparent (configurable alpha channel value) filter (an png, activity, don't know yet how) over the screen and this filter to not process touch events.
How can I do this ?

Later edit: no I don't think is possible what I want in this manner, I need another solution.
Basically I want to implement something similar to Screen Filter : http://www.appbrain.com/app/screen-filter/com.haxor

How this could be done ?
Thanks.

Comment: just guessing but your using standard views ? regarding your touch issue you can overide the ontouch in the view and do nothing else than super.ontouch that should prevent the event from being blocked

Answer (score -1):

You can set Clickable to false to the View of Activity. Which will make your view un-sensitive to touch events !
-Thanks

Comment: sorry, I don't want to process touch events, but I want that the activity under this semi-transparent (translucent) activity to process the touch events !